# How to use map() on a DataLoader dataset?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, transformer-model

I'm  trying to train a pretrained visual transformer (ViT) on a new dataset.
The dataset is made up of jpg images sorted into folders (train, val, test) and has 4 calsses.
I want to use map() on the dataset for preprocessing.
I added '**getitem**'  and '**len**' so that it'll be a map-style dataset.
But I still get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataLoader' object has no attribute 'map'
```

Here's the code:

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader 
class MyDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, path, transform):
        self.files = glob.glob(path)
        print(type(self.files))
        self.transform = transform
        self.labels = [filepath.split('/')[-2] for filepath in self.files]
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        file = self.files[item]
        label = self.labels[item]
        file = Image.open(file)
        file = self.transform(file)
        return file, label
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.files)
    
    
    transform=transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])
    
    train_data = MyDataset(train_path, transform)
    val_data = MyDataset(val_path, transform)
    test_data = MyDataset(test_path, transform)
    
    train = DataLoader(train_data , batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=3)
    val = DataLoader(val_data , batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
    test = DataLoader(test_data , batch_size=1, shuffle=True)
    
    
    feature_extractor = ViTFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained('google/vit-base-patch16-224-in21k')
    data_collator = default_data_collator
    
    
    def preprocess_images(examples):
        images = examples['img']
        images = [np.array(image, dtype=np.uint8) for image in images]
        images = [np.moveaxis(image, source=-1, destination=0) for image in images]
        inputs = feature_extractor(images=images)
        examples['pixel_values'] = inputs['pixel_values']
    
        return examples
    
    
    features = Features({
        'label': ClassLabel(
            names=['class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class4']),
        'img': Array3D(dtype="int64", shape=(3, 32, 32)),
        'pixel_values': Array3D(dtype="float32", shape=(3, 224, 224)),
    })
    
    preprocessed_train_ds = train.map(preprocess_images, batched=True, features=features)
    preprocessed_val_ds = val.map(preprocess_images, batched=True, features=features)
    preprocessed_test_ds = test.map(preprocess_images, batched=True, features=features)
```

What else can I do?

Comment: What is this `DataLoader` class? Can you provide its package definition?

Comment: Yes, sorry 
It's from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate the `DataLoader` for train, test and val dataset, you can point the flag `collate_fn=preprocess_images` function. You will have to update the function to match to your requirement.

*e.g.,*

```
DataLoader(train_data, collate_fn=preprocess_images, , batch_size=1, shuffle=True, num_workers=3)
```

See [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py)

To quote:

> collate_fn (Callable, optional): merges a list of samples to form a
> mini-batch of Tensor(s).  Used when using batched loading from a
> map-style dataset.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help
I'm getting this error:
''DataLoader' object is not subscriptable'
I think it might have to do more with training.
I used this script for training (just used my own dataset as shown above):
[https://github.com/The-AI-Summer/Hugging_Face_tutorials/blob/master/vit.py]

Comment: `DataLoader` object is non-indexable, only iterable. Please see in your code if you are using something like `train[5]`. Please see the documentation https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html on how these works.

Comment: I'm not using any index with train. My code after the the DataLoader function is identical to the hugging face tutorial.
I can't really figure out what to do next?